# Converse and The Negation of The Converse of The Statement: "For all positive real numbers x, there exists an integer n such that $\frac{1}{n} <x.$"

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

I am trying to express the converse and the negation of the converse of the following statement both in plain English language and in formal language.

"For all positive real numbers $x$, there exists an integer $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n} <x.$"

Given that the universe for both $x$ and $n$ are the set of all real numbers, I have expressed the statement and its negation  in formal language respectively as follow:

\begin{align*} 
\forall x,(x\in \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \exists n,(n\in \mathbb{Z} \wedge \frac{1}{n} < x)). \\
\exists x,(x \in \mathbb{R}^+ \wedge \forall n,(n\in \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \frac{1}{n}\geq x)).
\end{align*}

However, I am stuck on how to express the converse and the negation of the converse of the original statement.

Here is my attempted expressions for the converse and the negation of the converse of the original statement respectively.

\begin{align*}
\exists n,((n\in \mathbb{Z} \wedge \frac{1}{n} < x) \rightarrow \forall x,(x\in \mathbb{R}^+)).\\
\forall n,((n\in \mathbb{Z} \wedge \frac{1}{n} < x) \wedge \exists x,(x \in \mathbb{R}^+)).
\end{align*}

Each of the above statements is expressed in plain English language as:

\begin{align*}
&\text{"If there exists an integer $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < x$, then for every $x$, $x$ is a positive real number."}\\
&\text{"Every integer $n$ has some positive real number $x$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<x$."}
\end{align*}

I am not sure whether the above expressions for the converse and the negation of the converse of the original statement both in formal language and in plain English language are correct or not.

Comment: [Converse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_(logic)) applies to the conditional... What is the meaning of the converse is this case?

Comment: Having said that, the universal quantifier applies to the complete formula; thus you cannot use only for the consequent. It must be: $\forall x [(n∈ \mathbb Z ∧ \frac 1 n < x) →(x∈ \mathbb R^+)]$ that makes little sense.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Well, if we take this statement as "if $x$ is a positve real number there is an integer $n$ so that $\frac 1n < x$" the the converse would be. If there is an integer $n$ so that $\frac 1n < x$ then $x$ is a positive real number".... maybe.  This may not be a very useful or practical exercise....

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA On the statement $\forall x,((n\in \mathbb{Z} \wedge \frac{1}{n} < x) \rightarrow(x\in \mathbb{R}^+)).$,why is it not necessary to have an existential quantifier in front of the statement the statement $(n\in \mathbb{Z} \wedge \frac{1}{n} < x)$?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I have asked a question similar to this question before not long ago. I asked that whether the statement "For every $\varepsilon$, there exists an integer $N$ such that $1/n$ < $\varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$." can be expressed in the formal language form $\forall \varepsilon,(\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \exists N,(N\in \mathbb{Z} \wedge \forall n,(n \geq N \rightarrow 1/n < \varepsilon))).$ and someone have said that it is correct. So, is the expression in this comment in formal language wrong? Because, I have used the universal quantifier in the consequent.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The link to the question in the above comment is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4050306/questions-about-expressing-each-of-the-following-statements-in-formal-language-a

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I have also asked about how the statement "The equation $x^2+2x=15$ has a unique solution." can be expressed in formal language, and I have got one of the possible answers as $\exists x,((x^2 + 2x = 15)\wedge \forall y,(y^2 +2x = 15 \rightarrow x=y)).$ How can the statement have the universal quantifier inside the complete formula? Here is the link to the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4044483/expressing-the-statement-the-equation-x2-2x-15-has-a-unique-solution-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer to the converse of the statement in formal language is:

\begin{align*}
\forall x,(\exists n,(n\in \mathbb{Z} \wedge \frac{1}{n} < x) \rightarrow (x \in \mathbb{R}^+)).
\end{align*}

which is expressed in plain English language as:

\begin{align*}
\text{For every real number $x$, if there exists an integer $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < x$, then $x$ is positive.}
\end{align*}

The correct answer to the negation of the converse of the statement in formal language is:

\begin{align*}
\exists x,(\exists n,(n\in \mathbb{Z} \wedge \frac{1}{n} < x) \wedge (x \notin \mathbb{R}^+)).
\end{align*}

which is expressed in plain English language as:

\begin{align*}
\text{There exists a real number $x$ such that there is an integer $n$ which $\frac{1}{n} < x$ and $x$ is not positive.}
\end{align*}